# Como realizar una sentencia if en MySQL Procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql, sql, condiciones, stored-procedure

Necesito realizar una sentencia `if` en un procedimiento almacenado, el tema es este.

Si en la consulta viene 1 email, o más de un email... Para eso, la tabla tiene 2 campos, `email1`, y `email2`, y se debe validar si viene 1 email o 2, si vienen 2 es obvio que ambos campos vienen llenos.

¿Cómo harían ustedes la consulta?

Mi ejemplo:

```sql
select tu.email1, tu.email2 from tb_user as tu where id = '1234';

select IF(tu.email1 > 0 and tu.email2 > 0, "YES", "NO") as cantEmail;

--- otra solucion

select length(tu.email1) as email1;
select length(tu.email2) as email2;

if (tu.email1 > 0 and tu.email2 > 0) then
ejecuto el código
endif
```

El tema es que no me funciona al momento de ejecutar la query en un "archivo SQL".

Por ejemplo, al ejecutar la consulta `select IF(tu.email > 0 and tu.email2 > 0, "YES", "NO") as cantEmail;` me indica:

> "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'email1' in 'field list'"

Estaría muy agradecido por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿La columna se llama email1 o email? Porque el mensaje de error es ese, que no encuentra la columna llamada email1.

Comment: No es necesario el procedimiento, en la misma consulta lo consigues: `SELECT !isnull(email1)+!isnull(email2) noEmails FROM tb_user;`.

Comment: ¿“nadie de seguro puede solucionarlo”? En SO, hay una cantidad muy significativa de desarrolladores y muy diversificados, no creo que ese sea el comentario más adecuado, todo tiene solución =).

Comment: Creo que la explicación está algo enredada. Sería mejor que, en lugar de explicar solo el problema que estás teniendo, digas qué es lo que quieres lograr con esto. Algo como "quiero saber todas las filas que tienen 0, 1 o 2 correos en la tabla tb_user", o "si el usuario con ID 7 tiene 2 correos, quiero ejecutar un select y si tiene 1 quiero ejecutar un select distinto". Eso daría chance de, al entender de que se trata el tema, responderte. Y bueno, hay realmente buenos programadores por aquï, diría que lo más probable es que si te logras explicar, obtengas respuesta.